# How to throw an error when fprintf or disp is called?

Tags: matlab, debugging, error-handling

I have a large library of impenetrable code that writes out really annoying linebreaks. I can't seem to find where they are for some weird reason. So I was thinking if I could make MATLAB throw an error whenever `sprintf` or `disp` is called, I could find them. Is there a way to do this?

I tried `evalc` but all it gives is the output itself not from where it was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dbstop in`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html)

Sure you can overload `disp` or `fprintf`, or you can just tell the debugger to stop at these functions with `dbstop`. Then use `dbstack` to see where you are and how you got there.  It's OK that these are built-ins with no MATLAB code. It will stop right before the call:

```
>> dbstop in disp
Warning: MATLAB debugger can only stop in MATLAB code files, and "libmwbuiltins>disp" is not a MATLAB code file.
         Instead, the debugger will stop at the point right before "libmwbuiltins>disp" is called. 

>> dbstop in fprintf
Warning: MATLAB debugger can only stop in MATLAB code files, and "libmwbuiltins>fprintf" is not a MATLAB code file.
         Instead, the debugger will stop at the point right before "libmwbuiltins>fprintf" is called.
```

Looking good!

Consider the following test function `testdbstop` with a nested function `fprintTest`:

```
function testdbstop
x=1;
disp(x)
fprintTest(x)
    function fprintTest(x)
        fprintf('%d\n',x);
    end
end
```

Running it from the command line:

```
>> testdbstop
3   disp(x)
K>> dbstack
> In testdbstop at 3
K>> dbcont
     1
6           fprintf('%d\n',x);
K>> dbstack
> In testdbstop>fprintTest at 6
  In testdbstop at 4
K>> dbcont
1
```

There you have it -- disp is called on line 3 of `testdbstop.m`, and `fprintf` is called on line 6 of `testdbstop.m` in `testdbstop>fprintTest` called from line 4 of `testdbstop`.

Note: When you are done, remove the virtual breakpoints with `dbclear` (i.e. `dbclear in disp` and `dbclear in fprintf`).

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to throw an error. For example disp is called by workspacefunc whenever you exit the debugger. Setting a breakpoint makes it easier, if you want an error replace the `keyboard` with an error.

```
function disp( varargin )
builtin('disp',varargin{:});
x=dbstack;
%it's nessecary to exclude all calls which come via workspacefunc,
%otherwise it's impossible to quit the debugger.
if numel(x)>2&&strcmpi(x(2).file,'workspacefunc.m')
    return;
end
keyboard;
end
```

Place this disp.m on top of your path, it will call the builtin, thus you see what was printed and stop afterwards. Do the same for `fprint`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is write your own disp() function (which could generate an error with the error() function), save it as disp.m in your current Matlab path. This will override the built in disp() & allow you to find where it is called.

Alternatively, you could open up all the files in your library in something like Notepad++ and search across all opened files for the term "disp("

Answer (score 0):

Making `fprintf` throw an error is very easy since there are no overloaded methods for `fprintf`.

You can shadow the built-in `fprintf` by creating a new function called fprintf.m in your current directory (which is always highest in the Matlab path).  The function should contain code like this:

```
function fprintf(varargin)
error('Error message to help find fprintf statements')
```

Now when you run the impenetrable code, you will get an error whenever `fprintf` is called.

If the impenetrable code changes directories, your new fprintf.m may not get called.  In this case, I would place your custom fprintf.m code in a folder that is on the matlab path higher than Matlabs `fprintf` function.  You can check that it is higher by giving this command at the command line:

```
which fprintf -all
```

Matlab's built-in function should be shadowed and yours should be on top.  It should look something like this:

> > which fprintf -all
> >     C:\Users\MyName\Documents\MATLAB\fprintf.m
> >     C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\matlab\iofun\@serial\fprintf.m   % serial method
> >     built-in (C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\matlab\iofun\fprintf)  % Shadowed

Finding missing semicolons that are making variables is more difficult since there are many different disp methods.